# XML Schema validation ignored when fragment-level conformance is enabled?

Tags: c#, .net, xsd, xml-validation

From my sojourn with XML and Schema validation, it seems that when [fragment-level conformance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6bts1x50.aspx) is enabled for an [XMLReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx) instance, the XML source stops being validated against any [included Schemas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.schemas.aspx).

However I cannot verify this from the MSDN documentation as it doesn't seem to describe XSD Schema behaviour in light of conformance level. Also if I assume this problem is true, I cannot find a workaround for it.

**I would like to know how to validate a XML *fragment* against an XSD Schema.**

In my case I'm validating against the [XHTML 1 Strict Schema](http://www.w3.org/2002/08/xhtml/xhtml1-strict.xsd). By the fact deprecated HTML tags like <center> are not being flagged as invalid, this is part of the reason I believe fragment conformance ignores schema. Also when I use document-level conformance in the same scenario, validity errors are successfully flagged.

[For a code sample of the type of validation scenario I'm using see this](http://asp.dotnetheaven.com/howto/doc/Xml/ValidationReadingXML.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the answer in [this MSKB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318504) oddly enough titled **HOW TO: Validate XML Fragments Against an XML Schema in Visual C#.NET**  The bottom of the article states:

> NOTE: Only the type declarations and
>   the top-level elements in the XML
>   schema are validated against an XML
>   schema. Subelements are considered as
>   local and therefore cannot be
>   validated. In order to validate a
>   subelement, declare a top-level
>   element and refer to that.

I believe there is a mistake in that paragraph and the intention is to state `top-level elements in the XML`<strike>`schema`</strike> **`document/fragment`** `are validated against an XML Schema`

Because the Microsoft code sample starts its fragment at the top level (instead of arbitrarily inside a document) it works with validation. However in my case I'm taking a mid-document construct.

Correct me if my interpretation is wrong.

---

### Workaround/solution

A workaround is for me to stuff my fragments inside a top level element for the purpose of validation.

In other words if I'm dealing with the XHTML fragment:

```
<div>MY FRAGMENT</div>
```

I can wrap it for validation to [conform to the XHTML Strict Schema](http://www.webstandards.org/learn/reference/templates/xhtml10s/) as:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>HTML fragment enclosed, conforming to XHTML 1.0 Strict Template.</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div>MY FRAGMENT</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This solution works for me so I'll use it in the interim; whether or not a better solution exists I'm unsure yet.